# Does Scala's immutability mean the list can't be modified or the list and its contents can't be modified?

Tags: list, scala, oop, functional-programming, immutability

I'm learning Scala and function programming and its immutability concept.

If my code operates on a list of objects like this:

```
class Devices(
  val devices_df: Dataset[Row],
){
  private lazy val _devices = _initialize_list_of_devices()

  def devices(): List[Device] = {
    _devices
  }

  private[this] def _initialize_list_of_devices(): List[Device] = {
    val devices_list = ListBuffer[Device]()
    for (device <- devices_df.collect()) {
      devices_list += new Device(
        device.getAs[String]("DeviceName"),
      )
    }
    devices_list.toList
  }
}
```

And I initialize the list like this:

```
  val devices_list = new Devices(devices_df).devices()
```

And then later on, I update the objects in the list like this:

```
  for (device <- devices_list) {
    device.modify_instance_properties()
  }
```

The code works and I am able to modify the objects within the list.

However, when I try to add another object to the list with something like this:

```
devices_list += new Device("append another device")
```

it fails whether it is `val devices_list` or `var devices_list`.

I just want to sanity check that I am not misunderstanding things and want to confirm that these are true:

- immutability does not mean the objects in the list cannot be modified

  - the objects seem to be updating their properties just fine
- immutability does mean the list cannot be changed

  - I am supposed to not be able to add another object to the list or remove an existing object from the list

Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `List` is an immutable collection, which means that its contents can not be changed. An instance of a `List` will always contain the same objects.

The objects that the `List` contains can or not be immutable, if those objects can modify their contents then you can *"modify"* the `List`; but in reality the `List` never changed, since it still points to the same *(mutable)* objects.

A `val` is an immutable reference, when you do `val foo = x` you are saying that `foo` will always point to the `x` object *(which again, may be mutable or immutable)*.

PS: All your code can be simplified to:

```scala
final class Devices(val devices_df: Dataset[Row],) {
  lazy val devices =
    devices_df
      .collect()
      .iterator
      .map(device => device.getAs[String]("DeviceName"))
      .toList
}
```

Comment: Thank you for writing that up and posting the example code.  It's really helpful.

I'm getting hung up on the semantics here: `So List is an immutable collection, which means that its contents can not be changed. An instance of a List will always contain the same objects.`

"contents" can mean the list itself or the objects itself.  "same objects" can mean the same object with the same properties.

Comment: In order for it to make sense to me, would you agree with this wording?: `So "List" is an immutable collection, which means that the "List" itself cannot be changed. An instance of a "List" will always reference the same objects."  Would that wording still be true?

Comment: @ZhaoLi yeah that is exactly what I said, remember a `List` is either a `Nil` or a `Cons(a: A, tail: List[A])` so basically a chain of cells that have an object and a pointer to the next cell until you find the empty cell; so in this case a `List` being immutable means you can't change the cells, they will always be the same ones and point to the same ones.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think I understand the `Cons` part, but I think I'm okay for now.

Comment: For the example code you posted, how would you change: `.map(device => device.getAs[String]("DeviceName"))` to produce a list of objects, i.e. incorporating  `new Device(device.getAs[String]("DeviceName"))`?  Is there a slick Scala/functional way of doing it?

Comment: @ZhaoLi `....toList ++ List(device1, device2)` or something like that

Comment: wow thanks.  I've never come across the `++` operator before.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks again for your help 